# upgrade to 22.04 made Gnome metacity-flashback clock disappear

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 but now the clock is gone.

I've looked at dconf-editor, settings, but nothing in these applications is working now. [image: date and time settings]

the top bar with missing time is shown now:

[image: bar with missing time]

I can no longer access the logout button either.

when I type in the command:

```
con@e:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-year true
```

I get the error:

```
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.datetime”
```

obviously, the "upgrade" destroyed some very useful data.  How can I get my Gnome working again?

Comment: Is `indicator-datetime` installed?

Comment: @muktupavels that fixed the time, but how can I get the power menu back? i.e. logout, restart, etc.?

Comment: `indicator-power`, ` indicator-session`, `indicator-sound`, `indicator-application`. You might want also `*-printers`, `*-messages`, `*-keyboard` and `*-bluettoth`. Replace `*` with `indicator`.

Comment: @muktupavels thank you, that worked. The "Appearance" menu is now missing from Gnome settings, how can I get the "Appearance" tab back? I *want* to use Gnome, https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ue6w52/appearance_tab_missing_in_settings_ubuntu_2204_lts/ isn't a correct solution

Comment: Do you get any error/warning when trying to run `gnome-control-center background` from terminal?

Comment: @muktupavels I didn't get any warnings, but as the original post shows, there is no "Appearance" and curiously, Gnome Tweaks doesn't change anything anymore either.  How can I alter the system so that I can again alter the appearance/theme?