# Gnome metacity flashback "Appearance" Menu gone after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 22.04, ubuntu-gnome, metacity

I'm running Gnome metacity flashback on Ubuntu 22.04.  After the upgrade, I had some issues: [upgrade to 22.04 made Gnome metacity-flashback clock disappear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423536/upgrade-to-22-04-made-gnome-metacity-flashback-clock-disappear)

[image]

the problem is that "Appearance" is missing, and I can't get it back.  I want to use dark mode, but cannot access it.

If I look at Gnome tweaks, changes to the appearance simply don't take effect.

How can I again get the "Appearance" tab back to the settings menu?

Answer (score 1):

The "Appearance" tab is dedicated to the standard Ubuntu desktop. It will not appear if you use another desktop based on Gnome, such as vanilla Gnome or, in your case, the flashback session.

You still can change themes, but you have to do so using the dedicated tools of the flashback session. The Yaru dark theme, and all variants for the different accent colors are available on your system and should be picked up in the theming dialogs.