# Where are the dedicated tools to edit the flashback session in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, metacity

In this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1425567/1672331 they mention that there are dedicated metacity/flashback configuration tools. I am having difficulty finding these after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

In particular the top bar icons appear to be impossible to change once they've been added. I would like to increase the size of the icons and change or remove them.

Where do I find the configuration management tools for flashback metacity?

Comment: `Alt` + `Right click` on icon should give option to remove it from panel.